# UnsatisfiableError while installing basemap

Tags: python, conda, matplotlib-basemap

I've a Python 3.6 anaconda installation and wanted to install via conda install the basemap package. However, I get the error below:

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in
>   conflict:
>     - basemap
>     - zict Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

I see that the dependency for installing basemap is Python 2.7. How does it come that I am offered a basemap version for an older Python distribution, despite I'm running 3.6? What would you recommend as the next action to overcome this UnSAT Error?

Best regards

EDIT:
Now I get the following error, using

> conda install -c conda-forge basemap

Thank you for your idea. Now I get the following message:

> (base) C:\Users\someuser>conda install -c conda-forge basemap Solving
>   environment: failed
>
> ## >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>
> `$ C:\Users\someuser\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda install -c conda-forge
>   basemap`
>
> environment variables: REMOVED HERE!
>
> ```
>      PYTHONIOENCODING=1252
>    REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
>         SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
>
>  active environment : base
> active env location : C:\Users\someuser\Anaconda3
>         shell level : 1
>    user config file : C:\Users\someuser\.condarc  populated config files : C:\Users\someuser\.condarc
>       conda version : 4.5.2
> conda-build version : 3.4.1
>      python version : 3.6.4.final.0
>    base environment : C:\Users\someuser\Anaconda3  (writable)
>        channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
>                       https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
>                       https://pypi.python.org/simple/win-64
>                       https://pypi.python.org/simple/noarch
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
>                       https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
>       package cache : C:\Users\someuser\Anaconda3\pkgs
>                       C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
>    envs directories : C:\Users\someuser\Anaconda3\envs
>                       C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
>                       C:\Users\someuser\.conda\envs
>            platform : win-64
>          user-agent : conda/4.5.2 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.4 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.16299
>       administrator : False
>          netrc file : None
>        offline mode : False
> ```
>
> V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V V
>
> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for url
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/noarch/repodata.json Elapsed:
>   00:00.179536
>
> The remote server could not find the noarch directory for the
>   requested channel with url: https://pypi.python.org/simple
>
> As of conda 4.3, a valid channel must contain a `noarch/repodata.json`
>   and associated `noarch/repodata.json.bz2` file, even if
>   `noarch/repodata.json` is empty. please request that the channel
>   administrator create `noarch/repodata.json` and associated
>   `noarch/repodata.json.bz2` files. $ mkdir noarch $ echo '{}' >
>   noarch/repodata.json $ bzip2 -k noarch/repodata.json
>
> You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed. Use
>   `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current
>   state. Further configuration help can be found at
>   https://conda.io/docs/config.html.
>
> A reportable application error has occurred. Conda has prepared the
>   above report. If submitted, this report will be used by core
>   maintainers to improve future releases of conda. Would you like conda
>   to send this report to the core maintainers? [y/N]:

Any idea what went wrong here? The link https://pypi.python.org/simple/noarch/repodata.json is indeed not found/available.

Comment: What is the output of `conda config --show channels`?

Comment: the output is as follows:
channels:
  - https://pypi.python.org/simple
  - defaults

Comment: What if you delete that first channel? `conda config --remove channels pypi.python.org/simple`?

Comment: Oh yes! That did the trick - wonderful! I still have no clue why and how this channel (pypi) came to the conda installation. But thank you. Now it works like a charm! I mark this as solved! :)

Comment: @darthbith, how can I mark your comment as the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try "conda install -c conda-forge basemap"